# D3 pack - changing the radius based on parent's size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, hierarchy, bubble-chart, circle-pack

I am trying to use D3 v4 to create a series of bubbles, each containing one smaller child element. Working off this [circle pack example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321), and using the FlareVis bubble in the lower right as a reference since it only has one child.

I have changed part of the csv to read:

```
      flare.flex,18000
      flare.flex.FlareVis,2116
```

By giving the parent bubble a value I hoped that it would be resized independent of the value of it's child.

Instead the parent bubble seems to be calculated based only on the value of the child, even though the tooltip shows the parent's value as seen in the following image. What can I change in the code so that it calculates the parent's value?

Note: I am not trying to use padding to make the parent larger as both the parent and the child elements will each have separate values.

[image: D3 circle pack parent]

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: My code is identical to Mike Bostock's example but I've added a value to the flare.flex parent inside the .csv. Here is a live version from Blockbuilder:
http://blockbuilder.org/mbostock/ca5b03a33affa4160321

Comment: Okay. I ask because you are more likely to get help if people don't have to go through the trouble of creating a fiddle to try and find a solution.